# how to update google Sheet to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, api

MY table :test_tbl
[image: test_tbl]

i need to apply Where condition .
In that code update all row in Price Column .
code:

```
function UdateRecords() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  var start = new Date();
  var update = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE test_table SET Price ='" + "100" + "'");
  update.addBatch();
  var batch_1 = update.executeBatch();

  }
```

i need to update row where  item="cake" replace item="Pizza" Quantity="10" Price="500" and total_price="5000"

Comment: What's the relationship between total price and price?

Comment: no relation it's static data insert form google excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test_table 
   SET item = "Pizza" 
     , Quantity = 10
     , Price = 500
     , total_price = 5000
 WHERE item = "cake"
```